# knowrob visualisation_canvas

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced similar problem while running the visualisation_canvas to, as described in the knowrob basics tutorial. However, I keep getting this error message:

?- visualisation_canvas. ERROR: Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/knowrob/vis/MarkerVisualization Exception: (7) knowrob_vis:visualisation_canvas(_G2269) ?

I could find that MarketVisualization.java file is located at ~/knowrob/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_vis/knowrob_vis/src/main/java/org/knowrob/vis/MarkerVisualization.java

My testing environment consists of:
Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo, java version "1.7.0_72" are installed under knowrob.

Any hint would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201169/knowrob-visualisation_canvas/) by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you compiled your Catkin workspace using catkin_make?

EDIT:
Could you please try to start KnowRob directly with knowrob_vis as argument to make sure [this issue](https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob/issues/40) is not the problem?

```
rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_vis
?- visualisation_canvas.
```

EDIT 2:
Since we regularly build KnowRob from plain Ubuntu using docker, I am quite certain that it does work on Indigo/Trusty. It's difficult to debug from remote, but rosjava on Indigo seems to cause quite some problems for people, e.g. also [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/201594/knowrob-installation-failed-to-process-package-json_prolog_msgs/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/201616/how-to-chain-knowrob-and-rosjava-workspaces/).

Maybe the following Dockerfiles help you find the problem in your setup. Their syntax is explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/); basically, you have to run the commands in the lines starting with RUN, and instead of exporting the lines starting with ENV, you source the corresponding setup.bash as indicated in the comments. The first file installs rosjava and SWI Prolog on a fresh Ubuntu Trusty, the second one installs KnowRob on top of that.

https://github.com/knowrob/docker/blob/master/indigo-swi-rosjava/Dockerfile

https://github.com/knowrob/docker/blob/master/indigo-knowrob-interactive/Dockerfile

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on 2015-01-24**:
Thank you for your advice but the new way is still shows exactly the same error message:

?- visualisation_canvas.

ERROR: Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/knowrob/vis/MarkerVisualization
Exception: (7) knowrob_vis:visualisation_canvas(_G8565) ?

Note that One of my colleague installed and tried similar way on a different machine, but he faced the same error as above.